# Getting segmentation fault (core dumped) while trying to read a csv file in C

Tags: c, csv, segmentation-fault

I have a csv file with 10000 lines and when I debugged the code I noticed I was getting a segmentation fault on the last line. If I delete it the error disappears (Sorry for my english).

```
struct drivers {
    char *id;
    char *name;
    char *birth_day; 
    char *gender; 
    char *car_class;
    char *license_plate;
    char *city;
    char *account_creation;
    char *account_status; 
};

typedef struct drivers *Drivers;

Drivers initDriver (char *id, char *name, char *birth_day, char *gender, char *car_class, char *license_plate, char *city, char *account_creation, char *account_status) {
    Drivers driver = malloc(sizeof(struct drivers));
    driver -> id = strdup(id);
    driver -> name = strdup(name);
    driver -> birth_day = strdup(birth_day);
    driver -> gender = strdup(gender);
    driver -> car_class = strdup(car_class);
    driver -> license_plate = strdup(license_plate);
    driver -> city = strdup(city);
    driver -> account_creation = strdup(account_creation);
    driver -> account_status = strdup(account_status);
    printf("%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s", id, name, birth_day, gender, car_class, license_plate, city, account_creation, account_status);
    return driver;
}

Drivers initDriverFromLine (char *linha) {
    char *id = (strsep(&linha,";"));
    char *name = (strsep(&linha,";"));
    char *birth_day = (strsep(&linha,";"));
    char *gender = (strsep(&linha,";"));
    char *car_class = (strsep(&linha,";"));
    char *license_plate = (strsep(&linha,";"));
    char *city = (strsep(&linha,";"));
    char *account_creation = (strsep(&linha,";"));
    char *account_status = (strsep(&linha,";"));
    
    return initDriver(id, name, birth_day, gender, car_class, license_plate, city, account_creation, account_status);
}

int main () {
    FILE* Modulo1 = fopen("drivers.csv","r");
    if (Modulo1 == NULL) printf("Erro ao abrir o ficheiro.\n");

    char linha[1024];
    while (fgets(linha, sizeof(linha), Modulo1) != NULL) {
        initDriverFromLine(fgets(linha, sizeof(linha), Modulo1));
    }
    fclose(Modulo1);

    return 0;
}
```

My objective is to store the drivers into a linked list but as I'm trying to read the last line I get a segmentation fault error.

Comment: Why are you assigning every `strdup` to `driver -> id`? You then print all the other members, but they are undefined pointers. Copy/paste error?

Comment: It was my mistake, I already assigned every strdup to their respective places but it's still not working. I'm only using printf to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `fgets` loop you don't use the string that was read in the `while()` condition, but `fgets` another one and process it without checking if *that* is `NULL`. So you'll process **every second line** in the file, discard the others, and the last iteration (if the file has an **odd** number of lines) will segfault, because `fgets` returns `NULL`.

The loop should be

```
while (fgets(linha, sizeof(linha), Modulo1) != NULL) {
    initDriverFromLine(linha);
}
```

You don't make use of the return value from initDriverFromLine.

Also, in `initDriver ()` you have assigned every `strdup` to `driver -> id`. You then print all the other members, but they are undefined pointers. Is that a copy/paste error?

Comment: It was a copy paste error and I already fixed it. Changing the loop made it read until the last line but the first three lines are not printed.

Comment: Sorry, it's working. I'm dumb and forgot that my console had a line limit. Thnaks for the help!